# Highmaps UK map data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been searching the [Highmaps Map Collection](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/1.0.0/) and can't find the map data for the UK.  Does anyone know where to find this?  It seems strange that they would have country maps for so many different countries, but not have one for the UK.

Comment: I would think it is because your question not directly programming related, but rather looking for a resource.

Comment: Thanks Ondkloss, I'll try to find a better forum for these types of questions.

Comment: Better just to remember that StackOverflow is highly imperfect, and frequently sacrifices usability in the name of self righteous moderation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why it is not included in the list under any known name. In any case, the country code you are looking for is **GB**.

I'm assuming Highmaps uses [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2), which is a two letter country code standard, and as you can see, United Kingdom is listed under GB. I've provided the relevant links.

**United Kingdom (GB):**

Highmaps: http://www.highcharts.com/samples/maps-base.php?mapkey=countries/gb/gb-all

SVG: http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/1.0.0/countries/gb/gb-all.svg

GeoJSON: http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/1.0.0/countries/gb/gb-all.geo.json

Javascript: http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/1.0.0/countries/gb/gb-all.js